# How to build NDK Library over a previous build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK to build a library. I had everything working well, but then I needed to change a package name which is referenced in the library. I tried to build the library again once I made the change, by calling ndk-build in its folder, but this is the only output I get and it does not seem to be fully building:

```
C:\my-app\jni>ndk-build
Install        : libfilters.so => libs/armeabi/libfilters.so
```

This then leads to an unsatisfied link error when I try to run the application. I'll post my .mk file, but I don't think that should matter because my previous library was working with this .mk file. My guess is that there is a problem with me trying to build this one over the previous build. Any suggestions? Here's my .mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := filters
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := filters.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Once I do the rebuild as indicated, then I get the following error:

```
"Compile++ thumb : filters <= filters.cpp
C:/a-fa-outsidelands//jni/filters.cpp:4:28: fatal error: android/bitmap.h: No such file     or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ndk-build -B
```

forces a full rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, but now that leads to a new error. I edited my question to include it.

Comment: That's a new issue. Please accept the answer to this one and start a new question.